# Adding a limit to a join

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a limit to just one of my joins in mySQL. This is my SQL :

```
 select v.Consultant,SUM(a.marketing_fee) marketing_fee,v.agencyref, user.colorcode 
 from valuations v 
 join status_history sh on sh.ref = v.Ref 
 join user on user.username = v.Consultant 
 join answer a on a.title = v.Ref 
 where sh.status = 'booked' and sh.date between '$from' and '$to' and v.agencyref is not null 
 group by v.consultant
```

It is adding the sum 3x more than it should be because there are 3 entrys in the status_history table. Is there a way to limit the status history table or group them to get one result?

Comment: I don't see the `status_history` table in your query.

Comment: @CGritton i have edited, sorry i must have copied a previous statement -_-

Comment: The answer is probably going to depend on your `status_history` table and what you need from it. If there are three records in that table and they are all "booked", then do you need the most recent one? Do you need to divide by the number that there are? Will there always be 3?

Comment: There could be 0,1,2,3,4 etc, i need to check if there is a booked, and just show the latest one that was inserted for that reference for a report

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry ? i don't get it.. This question isn't for meta?

Comment: I'm lost for words.